What causes the Framework of my Eclipse RCP application to be stopped
I use Java 21 together with the Eclipse target platform 2024-06.
My Eclipse RCP application starts fine when launched inside the Eclipse IDE.
When I start the bundled program however, I see the splash screen for a few seconds, then the program stops unexpectedly. The last entries in the log file contain "Framework stop" and finally "Activator stopped".
...
2024-06-20T19:38:55,158  INFO [Start Level: Equinox Container: 1e7df525-5ce9-4c9b-b333-aa9125166a4d][[]] com.retrospective.ui.application.ResultServiceTrackerCustomizer - Bundle org.osgi.service.upnp                                        state:  4 stateName: RESOLVED
2024-06-20T19:38:55,159  INFO [Start Level: Equinox Container: 1e7df525-5ce9-4c9b-b333-aa9125166a4d][[]] com.retrospective.ui.application.ResultServiceTrackerCustomizer - Bundle org.osgi.service.useradmin                                   state:  4 stateName: RESOLVED
2024-06-20T19:38:55,159  INFO [Start Level: Equinox Container: 1e7df525-5ce9-4c9b-b333-aa9125166a4d][[]] com.retrospective.ui.application.ResultServiceTrackerCustomizer - Bundle org.osgi.service.wireadmin                                   state:  4 stateName: RESOLVED
2024-06-20T19:38:55,159  INFO [Start Level: Equinox Container: 1e7df525-5ce9-4c9b-b333-aa9125166a4d][[]] com.retrospective.ui.application.ResultServiceTrackerCustomizer - Bundle org.osgi.util.function                                       state:  4 stateName: RESOLVED
2024-06-20T19:38:55,159  INFO [Start Level: Equinox Container: 1e7df525-5ce9-4c9b-b333-aa9125166a4d][[]] com.retrospective.ui.application.ResultServiceTrackerCustomizer - Bundle org.osgi.util.promise                                        state:  4 stateName: RESOLVED
2024-06-20T19:38:55,315 DEBUG [Start Level: Equinox Container: 1e7df525-5ce9-4c9b-b333-aa9125166a4d][[]] com.retrospective.ui.application.registry.ApplicationRegistry - Application registry initialized
2024-06-20T19:38:56,007 DEBUG [main][[]] com.retrospective.ui.application.registry.ApplicationInstanceRegistry - Listening for application instances on socket 2029
2024-06-20T19:38:56,476 DEBUG [Framework stop - Equinox Container: 1e7df525-5ce9-4c9b-b333-aa9125166a4d][[]] com.retrospective.ui.application.Activator - Activator stopped
2024-06-20T19:38:56,476  INFO [Framework stop - Equinox Container: 1e7df525-5ce9-4c9b-b333-aa9125166a4d][[]] com.retrospective.ui.application.ResultServiceTrackerCustomizer - Bundle org.eclipse.osgi                                             state: 16 stateName: RESOLVED
2024-06-20T19:38:56,476  INFO [Framework stop - Equinox Container: 1e7df525-5ce9-4c9b-b333-aa9125166a4d][[]] com.retrospective.ui.application.ResultServiceTrackerCustomizer - Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator                       state: 32 stateName:   ACTIVE
2024-06-20T19:38:56,476  INFO [Framework stop - Equinox Container: 1e7df525-5ce9-4c9b-b333-aa9125166a4d][[]] com.retrospective.ui.application.ResultServiceTrackerCustomizer - Bundle com.retrospective.core.api       
...
2024-06-20T19:38:56,485  INFO [Framework stop - Equinox Container: 1e7df525-5ce9-4c9b-b333-aa9125166a4d][[]] com.retrospective.ui.application.ResultServiceTrackerCustomizer - Bundle org.osgi.service.wireadmin                                   state:  4 stateName: RESOLVED
2024-06-20T19:38:56,485  INFO [Framework stop - Equinox Container: 1e7df525-5ce9-4c9b-b333-aa9125166a4d][[]] com.retrospective.ui.application.ResultServiceTrackerCustomizer - Bundle org.osgi.util.function                                       state:  4 stateName: RESOLVED
2024-06-20T19:38:56,486  INFO [Framework stop - Equinox Container: 1e7df525-5ce9-4c9b-b333-aa9125166a4d][[]] com.retrospective.ui.application.ResultServiceTrackerCustomizer - Bundle org.osgi.util.promise                                        state:  4 stateName: RESOLVED
2024-06-20T19:38:56,495 DEBUG [Framework stop - Equinox Container: 1e7df525-5ce9-4c9b-b333-aa9125166a4d][[]] com.retrospective.core.service.bean.ServiceActivator - Activator stopped
2024-06-20T19:38:56,496 DEBUG [Framework stop - Equinox Container: 1e7df525-5ce9-4c9b-b333-aa9125166a4d][[]] com.retrospective.ui.table.UITableActivator - UITableActivator stopped
2024-06-20T19:38:56,501 DEBUG [Framework stop - Equinox Container: 1e7df525-5ce9-4c9b-b333-aa9125166a4d][[]] com.retrospective.core.shell.bean.ShellActivator - Activator stopped
2024-06-20T19:38:56,501 DEBUG [Framework stop - Equinox Container: 1e7df525-5ce9-4c9b-b333-aa9125166a4d][[]] com.retrospective.core.local.bean.LocalActivator - Activator stopped
2024-06-20T19:38:56,503 DEBUG [Framework stop - Equinox Container: 1e7df525-5ce9-4c9b-b333-aa9125166a4d][[]] com.retrospective.core.kernel.bean.KernelActivator - Activator stopped

I also started the .exe file from a cmd window but do not see additional information that would help me finding the problem.
Any idea what could cause the program to be stopped or how I can find the cause of the problem?

Maybe you get some hints by debugging or tracing your application.

@howlger: Thanks for your suggestion. Meanwhile I was able to fix my problem by other means (see my answer below).

With the help of a colleague, I found the additional log file <RCP App Home>/.data/.metadata/.log.
This file contained useful information that helped me find the solution for my problem after consulting this answer.
